# [avi][ako] Unless recreated, the L4 loadbalancer IP is not available after a while(almost a day)

Tags: kubernetes, avi

My Kubernetes Cluster uses AKO integration avi, my service (type: loadbalancer) resources have used L4 IP unable to access after a period of time (almost one day) (ping is not available, port is not available), only delete and then recreate the service resources The IP allocated by AVI (including the previously released IP) can continue to access, but this loop will continue after passing (almost a day).

I found these errors in my Ako Pod log

```
2022-03-01T06:04:30.725Z    WARN    lib/avi_api.go:69   msg: Unable to fetch data from uri /api/cluster/runtime Encountered an error on GET request to URL https://<my-avi-ip>//api/cluster/runtime: HTTP code: 401; error from Avi: map[detail:Authentication credentials were not provided.]
```

I confirm that my avi-secret configured username password can be logged in to the AVI page.